# How to convert binary into sign representation?

Tags: python, arrays

If an array consist of decimal number which represents as blocks('#') or empty(' ').
For example.

`A = [31,21,29,19,31]`  
represents
`['11111', '10101', '11101', '10011', '11111']`

and I want to have this array to be like this
`['#####', '# # #', '### #', '#  ##', '#####']`

Comment: Did you try something you can show us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with string formatting (here a [f-string](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/)) and a [translation table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods):

```
A = [31,21,29,19,31]  

trans = str.maketrans('01', ' #')
# {48: 32, 49: 35}

out = [f'{x:b}'.translate(trans) for x in A]
```

output:

```
['#####', '# # #', '### #', '#  ##', '#####']
```

Comment: you probabli need to fix the number of digit? `'{x:8b}'`

Comment: @ymmx good point, but here is looks like the leading spaces should be omitted

Comment: Yes, that's depending in what values are in A